# Repository „cdrom://elementary OS 5.0 _Juno_ - Stable amd64 (20181016) bionic Release“ does not contain the Release file

Tags: release-juno, apt

**How can i solve this ?**

```
E: Repository „cdrom://elementary OS 5.0 _Juno_ - Stable amd64 (20181016) bionic Release“ does not contain the Release file.

W: An update from this repository can not be performed securely and is therefore disabled by default.

W: For details on creating and setting repositories, see the apt-secure (8).

E: cdrom://elementary OS 5.0 _Juno_ - Stable amd64 (20181016) bionic Release is not (yet) available (Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Edit with `sudo`, using your favorite text editor, the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`

---

Using `nano` editor

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

---

- Add a hash `#` in front of every line that starts with `deb cdrom:`
- Run `sudo apt update`